# <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a1bd1e0 V:[UIButton:0x7a1b2c10'Button text'(0)]>

Tags: nslayoutconstraint

What does the `(0)` mean after `Button text` in this warning from Xcode:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a1bd1e0 V:[UIButton:0x7a1b2c10'Button text'(0)]>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the height, since the constraint is vertical.

V means vertical, the [] means the contents of, and 0 is the height.

Checkout Erica Sadun's excellent ebook, Auto Layout Demystified.  (Well worth the modest cost)

https://books.google.com/books?id=_VmPAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=erica+sadun+nslayoutconstraint+error+log&source=bl&ots=kXZJVAuz00&sig=BIS3PocjYsPjWR0oPobnBilAjaU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vuJGVd-FB4nHsAWB2IH4BA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=erica%20sadun%20nslayoutconstraint%20error%20log&f=false

-c